# Color each polygon according to group in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two issues with code below. One the code is not giving each polygon a separate color. Secondly, the code is adding a second legend for geom_polygon. How can each group be colored separately, so that a legend can be added?

```
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = LS_11_SC_RF_DFF, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = Class_Name.1_value)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Orange", "Green", "Yellow", "Blue")) +
  geom_polygon(data = LS_11_Val_DF, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), size = 1) + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colors =c("Red", "Pink", "Cyan", "Purple")) + 
  labs(title = "Landsat 2011 Image Supervised Classification", fill="Land Cover Classes",
       caption = "Author: Mandalorian") + 
  theme(text=element_text(element_text(size=16,  family="serif")),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  annotation_scale(location = "bl") +
  annotation_north_arrow(location = "tr", which_north= "true")
```

Comment: In the second geom_polygon you need to specify within the `aes()` by which variable to fill. I.e.  `geom_polygon(data = LS_11_Val_DF,  aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = group), size = 1)`

Comment: This returns an Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 24 needed but only 4 provided. And yes, the LS_11_Val_DF has 4 groups.

Comment: That error is related to this line, where you provide only 4 colours. You can either provide 24 colours or use a scale_fill_* that will select them automatically.
The culprit: `scale_fill_manual(values=c("Orange", "Green", "Yellow", "Blue"))`
It  also seems like it is `LS_11_SC_RF_DFF$Class_Name.1_value` which requires 24 distinct colours to plot.